# Most efficient way to find spatial order from a list of tuples (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.x, sorting, recursion

I have a circle-growth algorithm (line-growth with closed links) where new points are added between existing points at each iteration.

The linkage information of each point is stored as a tuple in a list. That list is updated iteratively.

[image]

**QUESTIONS:**

- What would be the most efficient way to return **the spatial order** of these points as a list ?
- Do I need to compute the whole order at each iteration or is there a way to cumulatively insert the new points in a orderly manner into that list ?

[image]

All I could come up with is the following:

```
tuples = [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (1, 6), (0, 7), (3, 7), (0, 8), (2, 8), (5, 9), (4, 9)]

starting_tuple = [e for e in tuples if e[0] == 0][0]
## note: 'starting_tuple' could be either (0, 7) or (0, 8), starting direction doesn't matter

order = [starting_tuple[0], starting_tuple[1]]
## order will always start from point 0

idx = tuples.index(starting_tuple)
## index of the starting tuple


def findNext():
    global idx
    for i, e in enumerate(tuples):
        if order[-1] in e and i != idx:
            ind = e.index(order[-1])
            c = 0 if ind == 1 else 1
            order.append(e[c])
            idx = tuples.index(e)


for i in range(len(tuples)/2):
    findNext()

print order
```

It is working but it is neither elegant (non pythonic) nor efficient. 
It seems to me that a **recursive algorithm** may be more suitable but unfortunately I don't know how to implement such solution.

Also, please note that I'm using Python 2 and can only have access to full python packages (no numpy).

This question has also been [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245191/python-most-efficient-way-to-find-spatial-order-from-a-list-of-tuples) on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for recursion. You may want to first convert the tuples to a `dict` to make it more readable. Then iterate over the `dict` to construct an ordered list.

In terms of efficiency (or time / space complexity), your code is \$O(n^3)\$ in time and \$O(1)\$ in auxiliary space. Note that `idx = tuples.index(e)` is not necessary at all, since `tuples.index(e) == i`. Making use of this would allow your code to be \$O(n^2)\$ in time. The most time-efficient solution is \$O(n)\$, which is also the time complexity of the proposed solution involving a `dict`. However, the auxiliary space complexity of that solution is \$O(n)\$ -- inferior to your original approach.

If you want to update the order after obtaining a new `tuples` list, you can keep the `dict` and iterate over the new `tuples`, comparing with values in the `dict` to see if there is any change. However, the efficiency of this approach would probably be in most cases worse than constructing a new `dict` from scratch.

---

```
from collections import defaultdict

def tuples_to_neighbors_dict(tuples):
  """
  Covert `tuples` to a dict mapping each point to a list of its neighbors.
  """
  neighbors = defaultdict(list)

  for (a,b) in tuples:
    neighbors[a].append(b)
    neighbors[b].append(a)

  return neighbors

def tuples_to_order(tuples, start=0):
  """
  Covert `tuples` to a list of points.
  """
  neighbors = tuples_to_neighbors_dict(tuples)
  order = []

  prev = None
  current = start

  while current != start or prev is None:
    # add the current value to the list
    order.append(current)

    # move to the next -- pick the neighbor which we haven't visited yet
    neigh = neighbors[current]
    new = neigh[1] if neigh[0] == prev else neigh[0]
    prev = current
    current = new

  return order
```

---

**EDIT**   I just now looked at the SO question and noticed that one answer is almost identical to mine